# Floating ttl input and ground short without pulldown

Tags: digital-logic, impedance, logic-gates, pulldown

A pulldown resistor seems to always be used for configurations where when the switch is open the normal state is low.
For example
[image]

The reasons always given are to avoid a short between voltage and ground when the circuit is closed, and also to avoid the input floating when the switch is open.

I understand the first point about the short but why would the input still be floating if we did in fact short it to ground and didn't use a pulldown resistor? Can someone explain? Wouldn't the noise / random charges have a path of least resistance to go into just the same as with a pulldown resistor?

Comment: " but why would the input still be floating if we did in fact short it to ground and didn't use a pulldown resistor..."  If you short the input to ground then it is, by definition, no longer floating.

Comment: That's what I thought, intuitively, which is why all the stuff I've read online have confused me. Therefore am I correct in surmising that the only reason for the pulldown is to prevent a short between ground and source?

Comment: Do you really mean TTL, as you mention MCUs and surely they are CMOS these days, not TTL?

Comment: Either, I suppose. I'm just trying to make sense of pull-up abd pull-down resistors for starters

Answer (score 0):

If you had a 1000 Ω pull-down resistor (for example), when the switch closes, the current from 5 volts to ground would be 5 mA. If you used a 1 Ω resistor, the current would be 5 amps. Either will work for the MCU but it would be ridiculous to pull 5 amps just to send a signal to an MCU. A short circuit can also be regarded as a pull-down resistor.

> *Wouldn't the noise / random charges have a path of least resistance*

I'm picking you up on this sentence because it's a common mistake to assume that all current or charge flows through the path of least resistance. Current distributes across a range of parallel paths with the highest current density being the path of least resistance.